# wtforms raise ValidationError if crediting amount is greater than account's balance

Tags: flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms, validationerror

I have a table called Account with two methods(Invest and Withdraw) I have trouble at withdrawing method. I would like to have a ValidationError message if the crediting amount is greater than the account balance.

here is my trial

```
def Withdraw(self):
        account = Accounts.query.filter_by(name=self.name).order_by(Account.id.desc()).first()
        if self.credit > account.balance:
            raise ValidationError('There is no enough balance in: '+ str(account.name)+ ' please try to Withdraw another account!')
        else:
            account_balance = float(float(account.balance) - float(self.credit))
            trans = Account(name=account.name, descrip=self.descrip, credit=self.credit,balance=account_balance)
            db.session.add(trans)
            db.session.commit()
```

I got this concept below code

```
def validate_email(self, email):
        user = User.query.filter_by(email=email.data).first()
        if user:
            raise ValidationError('This emaill is alrealy exist in our system please choose another email')
```

I hope that is enough to explain my question please let me get help ):

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Flask-WTForms validation is a specific (sub-classed) function that runs when you validate your form.

The best thing to do is hook into your form validation function by overwriting it:

```
class MyForm(FlaskForm):
    field1 = ..
    field2 = ..
    credit = ..

    def validate(self):
        """Overwrite the Base validation function"""
        rv = FlaskForm.validate(self)
        if not rv:
            return False

        # now custom validation code:
        account = Accounts.query.filter_by(name=self.name).order_by(Account.id.desc()).first()
        if self.credit > account.balance:
            self.credit.errors.append('There is not enough balance...')
            return False

        return True
```

If this returns True you are free to continue your app assuming that credit/debit operations can occur, otherwise it will yield validation error.

If I were you I would ensure that my database table has a constraint to ensure you cant commit bad data. The integrity of the database is higher priority and although webform validation is good it is not necessarily good enough to keep your database integral.